# WSO2 IS. package org.wso2.identity.sso and SSO SLO fro more than one application

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I can't find source for package org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.
In github repository wso2-attic/carbon-identity there are these classes, but there is note, that repository is no longer used for development and I find there 2 links:

```
https://github.com/wso2/identity-framework    
https://github.com/wso2-extensions?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=identity
```

But I didn't find there any classes from package org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.

I have some problems with SSO SLO from 2 applications:

I login to 2 applications: `a` and `b`.

Logout from one application works properly, but when I try to logout from second application, I get error
 [4] [IS]ERROR `{org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitLogoutRequestProcessor} -  ssoTokenId cookie not found in the logout request` 
and html:

```
SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On
Error when processing the authentication request!
Please try login again.
```

SAML Logout response has link

```
https://test2-sso2.auth.test.vu.lt:9443/authenticationendpoint/samlsso_notification.do?status=Error+when+processing+the+authentication+request%21&statusMsg=Please+try+login+again.
```

and SAML response parameter:

```
<saml2p:LogoutResponse Destination="https://test2-wso2.auth.test.vu.lt:9443/samlsso"
                       ID="_9cb47e1d90276bcc53d4b110d3573b82"
                       InResponseTo="fgehcpnbagimhhcacbaanopameodckepmopaoaek"
                       IssueInstant="2017-08-31T11:09:43.403Z"
                       Version="2.0"
                       xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                       >
    <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
                  xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                  >test2-wso2</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester" />
        <saml2p:StatusMessage>Session was already Expired</saml2p:StatusMessage>
    </saml2p:Status>

</saml2p:LogoutResponse>
```

So, I have 2 questions:

- where I can find classes from package org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml;
- maybe somebody could help me with my problem with SSO SLO?

We are working with WSO2 IS v.5.3.0. One of these applications was travelocity.com and another is our application with architecture similar to travelocity.com. We are working in multi-tenant architecture. Both applications (Service Providers) are configured in the same tenant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are looking for `SPInitLogoutRequestProcessor`. You can find it at [[1]](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-saml/tree/5.3.x). For IS 5.3.0, the SAML component related development happens in the 5.3.x branch.

For your query on SLO; when you have the 2 applications configured for single logout and you logout from one application, the Identity Server is invalidating the user's authenticated session and sends back-channel SAML logout request to the other session participants (App 2 in this case). So the 2nd application should invalidate it's user session upon receiving the logout request from IS.

The error you are seeing should be due to IS not being able to find a valid authenticated session (as the session is already removed) for the logout request. [[2]](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/06/28/how-saml2-single-logout-works/) has a detailed explanation on how the single logout happens in IS.

One other approach you can take is to check whether there's an existing authenticated session in the IDP side before sending the logout request. You can use a passive SAML request to check the status of the session and if the session is already there then send the logout request.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I could not find these classes because "master" branch have different structure. I'll try one of yours solutions. So far I was thinking that Wso2 Saml agent and for instance example application travelocity.com realised first of yours solution. But I didn't check it. Another question: how can I create and send passive SAML? Excuse me, if it is to simple question. I'm a newbie in SAML

Comment: One more question. How do you think what could be happened if I change class SPInitLogoutRequestProcessor so that when the session is not found I accept that as the session was logged out and SPInitLogoutRequestProcessor send answer "success"

Comment: To send a passive request, you have to set `IsPassive="true"` attribute in the  `AuthnRequest`. If you trace the SAML request sent by travelocity when accessing the `http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com/` you will see the passive request.

Comment: Regarding the 2nd question. It's not that you can't do it but I wouldn't recommend on making any changes in WSO2 side code when you have a standard way of achieving your requirement :)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I agree with you. Every change causes problems in the future